# Syntax for checking child interactions in kivy

Tags: python, inheritance, kivy, children

I am learning kivy from a book that involves making a paint app. The author at one point introduces new buttons on a canvas class (inherited from Widget) and says that we have to check if the click received by the application on the canvas, also lies on one of its children. In that case, we would neglect the former and act on the latter.
I thought of achieving this by looping through self.children, checking if the on_touch_down(touch) member function returns true for any child, and returning from the function if that was the case:

```html
class CanvasWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_color = get_color_from_hex('#FF0000')
        self.line_width=2
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        for child in self.children:
            if(child.on_touch_down(touch)):
                return
        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba=self.my_color)
            touch.ud['current_line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=self.line_width)
```

And this works fine.

However, I don't follow and would like to understand his shorthand syntax:

```html
class CanvasWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_color = get_color_from_hex('#FF0000')
        self.line_width=2
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        #I don't understand the following line
        if Widget.on_touch_down(self, touch):
            return
        #Widget refers to the parent class (I hope?) how does it check with the
        #children?
        
        with self.canvas:
            Color(rgba=self.my_color)
            touch.ud['current_line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y), width=self.line_width)
```

Any clarity is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's *not* checking any child widgets at all, it's only checking itself.  That line is explicitly calling the base class version of the `on_touch_down()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Widget` class is the base class for all the kivy widgets, and it handles the propagation of `touch` events to its children via its `on_touch_down()` method. Rather than referencing the `Widget` base class directly, a better approach is to use the `super()` method, like this:

```
    if super(CanvasWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch):
        return True
```

This does the propagation and returns `True` (to stop the propagation) if any of the children want the propagation stopped. The code in `Widget` that does this is:

```
    for child in self.children[:]:
        if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
            return True
```

Since it does not directly reference the `Widget` base class, the `super()` method is safer if you decide to change the base class of `CanvasWidget`.

Comment: But shouldn't widget.on_touch_down(self, touch) return true even if the CanvasWidget itself is clicked?

Comment: No, the `on_touch_down()` method just propagates the touches to its children (as long as the widget is not disabled). The philosophy of kivy is that every widget should get notified about every touch and have an opportunity to check if that touch is within its bounds. Note that returning `True` means to stop the touch propagation.